# Best way to filter selector against an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, filter, reduce

Lets say I have a selector `$('.items')` and I want to get every item except those that are contained within an array of jQuery item objects.

I could use `filter` or `grep` or `each` to go through every item selected, and on every item i could make another loop to see if it matches any in the disallowed array.

I am just wondering if there is either a shorthand way of doing this, or a more efficient way? What do you think is the best way of implementing this?

Comment: what does the array contain ... can you give an example ?

Comment: Can you explain in clear, what do you mean by `except those that are contained within an array.` ?

Comment: sorry i updated - it is an array of jQuery item objects that will definitely be contained within the results of $(.items)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `filter` as it's the most readable way, and it's the the purpose of the function- `filter`...

- `each` used mainly to do actions on **each** element in the set.
- `grep` is for arrays,  not jQuery objects, though it can be done with it, it shouldn't.

How I would do it:

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
$('...').filter(function(){
    return $.inArray(this.id, arr) === -1
});
```

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive response and the clean solution, will accept when i can

Comment: @VisioN, this comment still amuses me, do you remember what was its [context](http://stackoverflow.com/users/690854/thecodeparadox)?